# Dockerize Django with Celery worker/beat, RabbitMQ and postgresql

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, celery

I want to setup docker-compose for my app, which contains Django, Celery (+Beat), RabbitMQ and PSQL. My problem is that celery beat container does not work as intended (does not schedule a task with interval 10s).

Docker logs - celery beat wakes up in 5.00 minutes, celery worker works fine

```
celery-worker_1  | [2021-03-29 21:05:58,201: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
celery-worker_1  | [2021-03-29 21:05:58,225: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:205: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
celery-worker_1  |             leak, never use this setting in production environments!
celery-worker_1  |   warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
celery-worker_1  | [2021-03-29 21:05:58,225: INFO/MainProcess] celery@247ea26ee17b ready.
celery-beat_1    | [2021-03-29 21:06:00,525: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting default socket timeout to 30
celery-beat_1    | [2021-03-29 21:06:00,526: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
celery-beat_1    | [2021-03-29 21:06:00,749: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
celery-beat_1    | <ScheduleEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup() <crontab: 0 4 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>
celery-beat_1    | [2021-03-29 21:06:00,749: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 minutes
celery-beat_1    | [2021-03-29 21:06:00,751: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes.
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
      - rabbit
      - celery-worker

  celery-worker:
    build: .
    command: sh -c 'sleep 8; celery -A core worker -l INFO'
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
      - rabbit

  celery-beat:
    build: .
    command: sh -c 'sleep 10; celery -A core beat -l debug'
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
      - rabbit
      - celery-worker

  pgdb:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    restart: on-failure

  rabbit:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management-alpine"
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
    restart: on-failure

volumes:
  pgdata: {}
```

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://admin:mypass@rabbit:5672/'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+postgresql://news_user:news@pgdb/news'

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'scheduled_task': {
        'task': 'news.tasks.get_news',
        'schedule': 10.0
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the `settings.py` located? how did you load this file?

Comment: file `settings.py` is in `core` package. `Core` is on the same level as `docker-compose`.

Comment: are you loading it explicitly? https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/application.html#config-from-object